# how to secure swagger-ui with basic auth using spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-ui

i have a simple spring boot app with rest api and i need to secure swagger-ui.html with basic auth using spring security

i have already try to set in `Docket api` this:

```
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .securitySchemes(auth)
                .securityContexts(securityContexts)
                .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.my.package.directory"))
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                    .build()
                .apiInfo(getApiInfo());
```

and my spring security configuration:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
```

it even dont need any auth what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login-page-url")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
            User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("username-here")
                .password("password-here")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```